Finding polygon (sector) in a set that contains given point
I'm making a game engine where levels are sector based, sort of like in Doom or Duke Nukem 3D. I need to find a sector that contains needed point.
I thinked about going through all sectors in map and checking them with raycasting method, however there's three issues with this:

It's slow, going through tens or hundreds of sectors doesn't sound so good.
If I'm correct there may be problems if one sector is surrounded by another sector, causing engine to give wrong sector, however I'm probably wrong.
There may be some problems with raycasting in some angles and areas.

Is there any better ways to do this? Thanks

Hi! Maybe you could put your sectors in some kind of quadtree / kdtree / rtree?

Like https://github.com/viceroypenguin/RBush


going through tens or hundreds of sectors doesn't sound so good.

Tens or hundreds of sectors are not really a lot, unless you do this very frequently or the polygons are very complex, chances are that a naive check will perform well enough.
The simplest optimization is to do a preliminary bounding box check. If the polygons are very complex you could also compute simplified bounding and/or bounded polygons. The next step is likely some kind of tree structure, R-Trees are a typical structure for things that have a size, but you could also make a kd-tree work.  Note that a simple linear search is often fastest when there are few items, so most tree structures transition to linear search at some level.
Another approach is to just draw all the polygons to a bitmap using separate colors. You can then lookup the nearest pixel and use the color to figure out the corresponding polygon. This should give very fast lookup, but require more memory and have a limited resolution.
The recommended approach is to start with the simplest possible solution, measure the performance, and only continue optimizing if the performance is insufficient. That should give you a base line performance to compare your optimizations with. A simple reference implementation can also be of help when unit testing more complicated algorithms.

If I'm correct there may be problems if one sector is surrounded by another sector, causing engine to give wrong sector, however I'm probably wrong.

If polygons can overlap you need some way to figure out which one to pick. There are a bunch of alternatives:

Just return all polygons containing the point
Order the polygons, either implicitly by the order they appear in the list, or by assigning a "z order" that you can sort on. Pick the first/last that contains the point.
Ensure that overlap or partial overlap do not occur in the first place.


There may be some problems with raycasting in some angles and areas.

Not sure what this means. But you might need to ensure that your polygons are "well formed", i.e. no zero length edges etc.

This sounds reasonable and good enough, thanks
